# Difference between returning a variable and returning the value of a calculation

Tags: java, return-value

When making a method in Java that returns a value, I can always return the value of a calculation or a variable that holds said value. For example:

```
public int sum(int a, int b) 
{
    return a+b;
}
```

And:

```
public int sum(int a, int b) 
{
    int res = a + b;
    return res;
}
```

My question is, aside from readability, what is the difference between the first method and the second method?

How does the `return` statement work? Does it create a variable before "returning" it to the point where the method was called?

Which version is best, in terms of saving memory? 
I just gave a trivial example, but the question stands for every kind of returning method.

Comment: No, it returns a *value*...

Comment: You are returning an `int` either way.

Comment: Completely useless aside: to really "return a calculation", your method needs to have a `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer>` or `IntBinaryOperator` return type (and no input parameters), and then you can do `return (a,b) -> a+b;`. This will return an object which will add any two numbers you feed into it later. All of the above is just to illustrate how unlikely it is that you accidentally return a calculation.

Comment: Of course, I meant to say "return the value of a calculation", but it looks like everyone who answered got the idea

Comment: you are creating a redundant variable which will hold up memory unless garbage collectors clears it in second case. in any scenario, variable must not be created if not used.

Comment: @GabrielEdery I got the idea too. :) I just thought you might find it interesting.

Comment: @MohammedAtif `res` is a method-local scalar variable that lives on the [method frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6). No garbage collection is involved in cleaning those up.

Comment: @biziclop I still don't understand what you said there.. But I'm just a beginner so that's not a shocker...

Comment: @dhke can you then explain how the memory allocated to method local scalar variable is reused by some other variable?

Comment: @MohammedAtif When the function returns, the whole stack frame is popped and that's the end of your local scalar variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can always return a calculation or a variable that holds said calculation.

That's wrong. You're returning a value, not a calculation.

Other than your wording, there's no difference. The Java compiler will probably generate the same bytecode in both cases, because it'll consider `res` an intermediate placeholder to be optimized away.

To understand how Java's `return` statement works, you'd have to look at how the Java Bytecode ABI works. You'll notice the JVM is a stack machine - and thus, the return value will simply be top on stack at the end of the function call, if I'm not mistaken, no matter what you do before.

Notice that this is notwithstanding further compile-time optimizations – nothing says Javac might not "inline" a method call if it is free of side-effects. But as soon as we're talking "smart" optimizations, asking how specific language concepts work might be a moot point, as they might get optimized away.

Comment: The compiler needs to generate an additional stack push for the intermediate variable, because `res` needs a memory location to be inspectable. However, the JIT will probably do away with the superfluous assignment quickly enough.

Comment: @dhke why would a method-internal variable need to be inspectable?

Comment: Did you misread that as introspection? Setting a breakpoint right before function return is something I do quite often. And having the return value in a named variable right there is really quite handy.

Comment: @dhke I might be too much of a C/C++ developer to be used to this, but: aren't you just assuming that this breakpoint will *exist*? Imho, a compiler configured to generate release code would have no reason to keep that purely intermediate value; i.e. a pop *directly* following a push is very obviously easy to eradicate.

Comment: Java is not like C++. The code you debug _is_ the exact same code you release to production. (You can strip some variable names, but the byte code is the same.)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thinking about it, true. The rationalizing end of this would be inside JIT compilation to the target machine.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly. And the moment you set the breakpoint, this prevents the JIT from optimizing away the line with the breakpoint.

Comment: Javac does *not* do inlining, it did in early versions and it caused a load of problems. Since then inlining has become the sole responsibility of the JIT.

Comment: @Durandal ah, those days back with JDK 1.1 when `javac` had a `-O` switch that actually did something.

Comment: @dhke aaand now I don't feel old anymore, since the version of Java I learned came with JRE1.3 and the last version I personally touched was 1.4

Answer (score 0):

The first example is more readable and there's less chance of maintenance errors because you don't have some variable that could be accidentally clobbered before the return statement.

There are also data-typing issues that could be introduced between the data type of the method, the data type of your 'res' variable and the data type of the expression being computed. That's not a problem in your example but introducing that intermediate variable for other reason than you have demonstrated is inherently riskier than just putting the expression in the return statement.

Comment: I see now. My bad, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is a stack machine, the return value is always on the stack. If you compile both functions, you will see that the generated code is indeed different:

```
public int withVar(int a, int b);
  Code:
     0: iload_1 (int a)
     1: iload_2 (int b)
     2: iadd
     3: istore_3 (int res)
     4: iload_3 (int res)
     5: ireturn

public int withoutVar(int a, int b);
  Code:
     0: iload_1 (int a)
     1: iload_2 (int b)
     2: iadd
     3: ireturn
```

As one can see, the longer version actually fills a third local variable slot (`istore_3`). Since that value is never used, however, any sane JIT will optimize the superfluous operations away quickly.

So for speed: Just don't bother. With regard to readability? It depends ... I found idioms like

```
public void func() {
    final int res;
    // do something
    return res;
}
```

quite handy at times.

- The compiler checks for single assignment of `res`, so with only a single return, you have a compile-time-guarantee of no fallthrough paths in the code.
- Setting a breakpoint on `return res` and having the to-be-returned-value in a named variable is often quite handy.

I wouldn't go into the trouble for a one-liner, though.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: They are the same, only the first one is (IMO) more readable.

Longer answer:
Processors don't know anything about variables (and in the end code compiled by the JVM will run on a processor too), all they know are registers. When you return a value that value has to be stored in a register (let's call that register **return**). So, the compiler doesn't care if you gave your return value a name or not, all it knows is that to return your computed value it has to put it into register **return** and that's what will happen. a+b will be calculated and stored in the register.

Only for a very, very dumb compiler would there be any difference in memory usage or speed: One could think of a compiler that stores the second example in two registers (first it calculates the result into one, then it copies that result into the return register), while the first one will only use on register, but that doesn't happen in reality - all compilers are smart enough to figure out that you can store your result directly in the return register.